# Compare two objects with ng-repeat to set an active class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set an active class for a users item list.

This is the view.

```
<div ng-controller="ItemController as vm">
    <ul>
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="x in vm.items">
              <input type="checkbox">
              <span class="check_title">{{x.item_name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

"vm.user_items" is sent to the view.

"vm.items" is also sent to the view.

All the values are in "vm.items". Users might only have two items but I want to show all of them and then add an "active" class or "selected" parameter to the input when matches are found.

How would I do this? Do I somehow compare them within the controller function before sending an object through to it?

Thanks!

Comment: So you need to find the intersection between `vm.user_items` and `vm.items` and then highlight those in the view, right? I'm sure there is a way to do this in the markup, but it's going to be somewhat inefficient and kludgy so I highly recommend doing that in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Context**

You didn't show us how `vm.user_items` is defined so I'm assuming it is an array of references to the `vm.items` object, rather than ID lookups or hard-coded duplicate clones.  (If not, the answer would change a bit.)  So assuming your data is something like:

```
vm.items = [
    {id: 1, item_name: "Item #1"},
    {id: 2, item_name: "Item #2"},
    {id: 3, item_name: "Item #3"},
    {id: 4, item_name: "Item #4"},
    {id: 5, item_name: "Item #5"},
];

vm.user_items = [
    vm.items[2],
    vm.items[4]
];
```

**Solution**

You can use `ng-class` to set the class.  You set a class attribute based on a controller value like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-class="{active: vm.user_items.indexOf(x) != -1}">
```

This code checks whether the current `vm.items` iteration (`x`) is a member of `vm.user_items` and sets the `active` class if `true`.

Here is a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/gcL6q0vo/)